# Not able to restore databases from blob container using T-SQL

Tags: azure-blob-storage, restore, sql-server-2017

I am backing up my databases to an Azure blob storage. I am able to backup and restore from maintenance plan. However I am not able to restore databases with script. Below is the T-SQL I am using:

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name
FROM URL = 'https://StorageAccount.blob.core/Container/FileName.bak'
WITH CREDENTIAL   = 'https://StorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/Container', STATS = 10
```

I am getting this error:

> Msg 3225, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Use of WITH CREDENTIAL syntax is not valid for credentials containing a Shared Access Signature.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You credential is wrong, please follow this link to [create a credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-2017#create-a-sql-server-credential).

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL mycredential   
WITH IDENTITY= 'msftutorialstorage', -- this is the name of the storage account you specified when creating a storage account   
SECRET = '<storage account access key>' -- this should be either the Primary or Secondary Access Key for the storage account
```

Then in your restore code, use this credential like below:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2016 
FROM URL = 'https://msftutorialstorage.blob.core.windows.net/sql-backup/AdventureWorks2016.bak' 
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'mycredential',
STATS = 5 -- use this to see monitor the progress
GO
```

Comment: I am now able to backup-restore with script, thank you.

Comment: Hello, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, could you please mark it as an answer? follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) : To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks.

Comment: I have already commented that this resolved my issue. How do I mark this as an answer?

Comment: @IftekharIlm, what happened?